# Dynamically create html table rows based on List of records

Tags: apex, emailmessage

I need to pass a list of records into the email body in apex code. I am looking for the code sample or an Idea to start doing this. so far i am doing this.

Java script button on detail page. onclick calls a webservice method in a Apex class and sends an email with the list of records. All this code is part of my POC.

Button Code:

```
{!requireScript("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")} 
{!requireScript("/soap/ajax/20.0/apex.js")} 

var retStr; 
var accId = "{!Account.Id}"; 
alert('**** Acc Id'+accId) 
retStr = sforce.apex.execute("MyWebServiceTest","makeContact",{accId:accId}); 

alert('The method returned: ' + retStr); 

document.location = '/{!Account.Id}';
```

Class Code:

```
global class MyWebServiceTest{
    webService static Id makeContact(Id accId) {
        List<Contact> cntList=new List<Contact>();
        cntList = [Select Id, Name from Contact where AccountId=:accId];
        string template ='<html><head><style> body {font-family:verdana; font-size:13px;}</style></head><body>';

        template += // Here I am expecting to add the cntList records to the template;
        Messaging.Email[] emailList = new Messaging.Email[0];
        for (id userId : userIds) {
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            message.setTargetObjectId(userId);
            message.setSaveAsActivity(false);
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setHtmlBody(body);

            emailList.add(message);
        }
    }

    if (!emailList.isEmpty())
        Messaging.sendEmail(emailList, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tables are constructed of a `<table>, <tr>` for every row, a `<td> </td>`for every cell, a `</tr>` at the end of each row of cells, and a closing `</table>` tag. Its a matter of you working out what you want yours to look like isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem before and came up with a solution.   Basically, you can append the table to your setHtmlBody text value by passing in a list of records (be sure to change to appropriate sObjectType).

```
public static string getTableEmailBody(List<Lead> myList){

    String htmlBody = '';

    //open table..
    htmlBody = '<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse"><caption>Request Summary Data</caption><tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>';

    //iterate over list and output columns/data into table rows...
    for(Lead l : myList){

        String myName = l.Name; if(l.Name == null){myName = '[Not Provided]';}
        String myPhone = l.Phone; if(l.Phone == null){myPhone = '[Not Provided]';}

        htmlBody += '<tr><td>' + myName + '</td><td>' + myPhone + '</td></tr>';

    }

    //close table...
    htmlBody += '</table>';

    system.debug('Email Body: ' + htmlBody);   

    return htmlBody;

}




//see output from above method...
List<Lead> myList = [select Name, phone from Lead where name != null LIMIT 15];

getTableEmailBody(myList);
```

You can run this in the execute anonymous window to see sample output.

Comment: awesome!  i'm sure there's a much mor efficient solution, but I feel this just gets it done